# How to speed up django development - Code reload

Tags: python, django, macos, docker, development-environment

I have been moving from php to python for my web-development. Have selected django as my prefeered framework. One thing that bugs is the time it takes for my changes of the python code to reload during development. ~10 sec roughly.

Probably some of my seconds are due to my selected setup of docker-for-mac with mounted volume. But even if it was down to 5sec it would be annoying. I have moved away from the built-in django development server, over to apache 2.4 with `mod_wgsi`, this improves the speed of the application a lot, but no the python code reloading.

I know it's like comparing apples and oranges, but coming from php my code changes are available immediately. Does anyone have any tips to speed this up?

Comment: It is a bit unclear to me how you exactly test. Django has some tooling that will automatically restart the server (typically within ~1-2 seconds) if you rewrite files.

Comment: Yes, this is what I refeer to as "django development server" the `manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80`. Even with that, the avrage reload time was 5 - 10 sec. 1 - 2 sec would not be a problem of course. But I'm not getting that with docker and mounting a volume. I will try to run it all without docker, and see if that is the cause of the problem. I know docker-for-mac has some mounting of volumes read/write speed issues. But they have improved a lot of late, and I also used docker when I was using php, without much degration of performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traced it back to slow disk access with Docker for Mac.